# Search summary should include the "deleted" option

Tags: bug, search

When using the site search there is a verbose summary of the search query shown, which includes the search string and any advanced search options used.

e.g.:

> [image]

The "deleted" option isn't shown though (all others options I tried are).

On a site where I have 10k it shows "user <my-user-id>" (which although correct, is confusing):

> [image]

But on a site where I am a mod (i.e. I can search all deleted posts), it shows nothing (and if I search *only* for deleted posts there is an [empty space where the summary should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggt7t.png)):

> [image]

The "deleted" option is listed in the search tips in the sidebar
 so it's not some hidden feature and I don't see any reason for it not to be included. The "user" part could probably be omitted; it's covered by the banner above the search results and it isn't explicitly being searched, "deleted" should be shown regardless though.